# Is there a way to generally calculate the size dependent number of arrangements of surface atoms on a wurtzite nanocrystal?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, geometry

This question I believe could be tackled with some field of mathematics but I am not sure which one.

A more basic form of this question is:
If a sphere of radius (r) and origin (x,y,z) is used to define atoms that are "in" a cluster of atoms whose positions are defined by a repeating crystal lattice, what are all the possible arrangements of atoms (for a given radius) resulting from changing the origin of the sphere to different places in the repeating lattice?

If the crystal lattice structure is known then I would assume that there finitely many different clusters of atoms that can be created using the "cutting" sphere and that the number unique atom clusters (arrangements) can be calculated for a given radius. Is there a field of mathematics that would be useful for investigating this?

The two atom basis crystal structure is defined by the vectors:

<(0 + i)*a + (0 + j)*b + (0 + k)*c> for element 1

<(1/3 + i)*a + (1/3 + j)*b + (1/2 + k)*c> for element 1

<(0 + i)*a + (0 + j)*b + (u + k)*c> for element 2

<(1/3 + i)*a + (1/3 + j)*b + (1/2 + u + k)*c> for element 2

where i,j,k are just integers substituted into the following vectors to give the Cartesian x,y,z coordinates of an atom in the lattice.

a =<0.5, Sqrt(3)/2, 0>*4.2985

b=<-0.5, Sqrt(3)/2, 0>*4.2985

c=<0,0,1>*7.01515

u=0.375

Comment: Could you include the structure of the crystal, or provide a reference? This is an interesting question. I think the answer would involve some combination of lattice theory, geometry, and group theory.